# how to require a specific package version in tox?

Tags: python, tox

In my `tox.ini` file, the dependencies are installed via the `requirements.txt` file which is also used by `setup.py`, as follows:

The `requirements.txt` file contains the acceptable range of `django` packages, depending on the python version installed, as follows:

```
Django>=1.11,<2 ; python_version == '2.7'
Django>=1.11,<3 ; python_version > '3'
```

For python3, I want to make sure the tests run on `django 2.0` as well as the latest `django 2.1+` that will be installed by default, obeying the version constraints specified in the `requirements.txt` file. To achieve that, I force the installation of the desired django version with commands, as follows:

```
[tox]
envlist = {py27,py3}-django111,py3-django{20,21}

[testenv]
deps =
    -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt

commands =
    django111: pip install 'Django>=1.11,<1.12'
    py3-django20: pip install 'Django>=2.0,<2.1'
    py3-django21: pip install 'Django>=2.1'
    pytest
```

Ideally I could just add to the `deps` variable like so:

```
[testenv]
deps =
    -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt
    django111: Django>=1.11,<1.12
    py3-django20: Django>=2.0,<2.1
    py3-django21: Django>=2.1

commands =
    pytest
```

But `pip` does [not support double requirements and will throw an error](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988) even though there is no conflict in how the version constraints are specified.

The drawback of using `commands` to override the installation is that it needs to remove the `django` package version installed via `requirements.txt` to install the desired one. Is there a way to avoid that extra step?

Answer (score 2):

One trick is to move the requirement from `requirements.txt` into `setup.py` - where it's loosely pinned so that all your django versions are possible. For example

```py
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        "Django>=1.11,<2.1",
    ]
)
```

and then use your second suggestion in `tox.ini`

```
[testenv]
deps =
    -r{toxinidir}/requirements.txt
    django111: Django>=1.11,<1.12
    py3-django20: Django>=2.0,<2.1
    py3-django21: Django>=2.1

commands =
    pytest
```

... so long as the Django requirement isn't listed in `requirements.txt`.

This works because the `pip install` is split in two parts, the first from `tox:deps` where you specify the hard requirement, and the second from the equivalent of `pip install -e .` where the `setup.py` has the looser requirement.